# How can I check a date is before a given time of day using Date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have written the following code (and accompanying unit tests) and it works fine from what I can tell. However I'd like to use [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) to do this as my project is using this for most date-related code and I'd rather avoid maintaining extra code.

However I can't find out how to do time of date comparisons in the [Date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started).

**How can I check a date is before a given time of day using Date-fns?**

```
const isBeforeTimeOfDay = (date, hours, minutes) => {
  const dateHours = date.getUTCHours();
  const dateMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  if (dateHours < hours) {
    return true;
  }
  if (dateHours === hours) {
    if (dateMinutes < minutes) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: did you try isBefore ? https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/isBefore

Comment: @scr2em I looked at isBefore(), yes. isBefore() compares two dates, rather than doing a time of day comparison. I could make a second date (on the same day as the first, with the time of day set statically) but that seems somewhat indirect.